# React: What is the performance penalty of calling setState after mutating the state directly in the component?

Tags: reactjs, state, state-management

Since the component's render method is called with each setState*, I was wondering about the performance penalty if I directly modify the state properties, call setState({}) with an empty object, and let the component fully render itself. This has an interesting side effect in the state management: The state in this case used as a mutable object rather than immutable one. Since the component will re-render with the new state values after the setState call, it will reflect the new values in the view. Of course, mutating the state is not recommended by the React team as they suggest the state should be treated as a readonly object, but nevertheless dealing with a mutable object becomes easier to do state management in some cases.

I know this is not the best practice and probably will raise some eyebrows immediately, but I cannot stop and ask for the performance impact or any other potential problems it may cause in a typical application.

Take a look at the following example for a simple demonstration: https://codesandbox.io/s/k5zy9zw8kv

So, please let me know what you think.

Thanks.

* Unless shouldComponentUpdate has been implemented within the component and returning false based on the current state and the nextState value.

PS: My personal opinion, for state management, it is better to use MobX for mid-sized to large scale applications. My question is mostly for relatively small applications. I think both react and redux are making state management unnecessarily complex than it should be. As a developer with OO background I would like to see simpler and more elegant solutions.

Comment: Your comment regarding mutating state bring easier is wrong. In my opinion it's not easier to do but it requires less thinking. What is immutable or read-only...it means your data and state is decoupled from your components...if you think this is harder try creating relational ui's where multiple components require the same data and have those components being able to edit the same data...nightmare of epic proportions

Comment: Performance would be your least concern with this approach. It is not just some "best practice", immutable state is a core idea of react library. Trying to work around it is like putting a horse in front of your car.

Answer (score 0):

## This is a terrible idea.

#### 1. Officially unsupported

Direct state mutation is undocumented, unsupported and untested, so the React team can change the behaviour across versions (without testing/documenting it).

#### 2. Breaks lifecycle methods

You break several lifecycle methods such as `componentDidUpdate` as `prevState` will not be the state before the mutation, so you give up your option of using these methods should you need them in the future.

#### 3. Keep state shallow instead

> dealing with a mutable object becomes easier to do state management

You probably get this feeling when you have deeply nested states, so modifying a nested property (eg. `product.quality`) requires cloning the whole object (eg. `products`) first.

It's recommended to keep your states as shallow as possible, both for state change simplicity and easier performance optimisation. Eg. if you state is shallow, declaring it as `PureComponent` will avoid it calling `render` when parent component re-renders with no changes to the child component.

In your example, you can move the state to `Product` instead:

```
class Product {
  state = { quantity: 0 };
  ...
  this.setState(prevState => ({ quantity: prevState.quantity + 1 }));
}
```